# iOS AVPlayer won't play audiobook but MPPLayerController will

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer

I'm developing a podcast/audiobook application.  AVPlayer is working great for playing podcasts but won't play audiobook from audible.com.  It will play audible files in MPMusicPlayer.  Is that b/c of proprietary format?  I'm just trying to figure out if I need to totally refactor my app to use mpmusicplayer or use both players by audio type.
THanks!  This forum has been so helpful!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AV--- classes are lower-level. There are a lot of things handled automatically by the MP--- classes that you have to do yourself when you use classes from AVFoundation.

In my projects, I use the MPMoviePlayerController and related classes instead of using the AVFoundation classes, whenever I can.  Saves me a lot of time.  Only when the project requirements can't be handled by the MediaPlayer framework do I use the AVFoundation classes.

In this specific case of audio books from Audible, it's likely that there's some encryption on the book or the connection that is being handled by the MediaPlayer framework.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I started using MPMusicPlayerController but switched to AVPlayer based on a thread here saying that's how you can keep playing in the background.  Will MP framework keep playing in background using applicationPlayer?

Comment: I believe that background playback depends only on your application's shared audio session, and as long as that shared audio session is setup as `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback` it will continue. Check out [AVAudioSession](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient) on developer.apple.com for more details.

Comment: You would set the shared audio session with code like this `[[AVAudioSession sharedSession] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error]`

Comment: Thanks again.  I do have AudioSession setup.  I've decided for audiobooks in order to play in background i'll just use the ipod instance on mpmusicplayer inside a seperate viewcontroller than my podcast player (AVPlayer).  It also makes sense to do b/c I can do more specific features geared to audiobooks...

Comment: Ok. Cool.  If you've figured out what you want to do, can you click the checkmark next to this answer?  That way, everyone knows that you've moved on.